# Difficulties accessing json values in request body of powershell azure function

Tags: json, powershell, api, azure-functions

I have an Powershell Azure function that receives a (json) string as request body. I need to access the values of `XMLA_String`, `WorkspaceId`, and `DatasetId` in order to set them to variables. Please let me know how

The following body is received:

```
"{\"XMLA_String\":'{\"refresh\":{\"type\":\"full\",\"objects\":[{\"database\":\"<db>\",\"table\":\"<tab>\"}]}}',
\"WorkspaceId\":'<workspaceid>',
\"DatasetId\":'<datasetid>'}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the line breaks in your sample JSON are just a formatting artifact, it looks like you're getting *doubly* JSON-encoded data, strangely.

Therefore, try applying [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) *twice* (which you've since confirmed solved your problem):

```sh
# Sample response received.
$json = @'
"{\"XMLA_String\":'{\"refresh\":{\"type\":\"full\",\"objects\":[{\"database\":\"<db>\",\"table\":\"<tab>\"}]}}',\"WorkspaceId\":'<workspaceid>',\"DatasetId\":'<datasetid>'}"
'@

$json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The above outputs a `[pscustomobject]` instance with properties `XMLA_String`, `WorkspaceId`, and `DatasetId`:

```
XMLA_String                                                                 WorkspaceId   DatasetId
-----------                                                                 -----------   ---------
{"refresh":{"type":"full","objects":[{"database":"<db>","table":"<tab>"}]}} <workspaceid> <datasetid>
```